# How can i display the full text on a label?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

i want to display some data into a label but it is not showing the full text. How can i fix this behaviour ? I set the lines to 0, but is still not working.

Comment: source code of viewController ?

Comment: @developper I dont think is relevant to the question, because the view is made in interface builder .

Comment: But here's the thing - how can anyone else (besides you) duplicate the issue you are facing? You've posted nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set horizontal compression resistance to 1000 (Required).

You can do it in the storyboard or programmatically.

```swift
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

[image]

Comment: Is working now, but now is not showing "Address" anymore.

Comment: You should do the same for that label as well.

Comment: @Alex Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped. Thanks :-)

Comment: Im still struggling a bit, now it shows me the address, but for some reasons, dont know why, it still shows the text with "..." on some addresses

Comment: @Alex Try adding required resistance compression, also in the vertical dimension. For both labels.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a guaranteed height like `equal 50` set a minimum height like `>= 50` that ways it will keep on expanding as required.